# Relationship between Bhattacharyya and Euclidean distance of two probability vectors

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics, measure-theory

Suppose we have two probability vectors $\mathbf{p}=(p_1,p_2,...,p_k)$ and $\mathbf{q}=(q_1,q_2,...,q_k)$. Define their Euclidean distance as
$$d_E(\mathbf{p},\mathbf{q}) = \sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^k (p_i-q_i)^2}$$
and their Bhattacharyya coefficient as
$$BC(\mathbf{p}, \mathbf{q}) = \sum_{i=1}^k \sqrt{p_iq_i}.$$
Is there any relationship between the two ? In particular, if we have a sequence of probability vectors $(\mathbf{p}_n, \mathbf{q}_n)_{n \geq 1}$ such that $d_E(\mathbf{p}_n, \mathbf{q}_n) \sim n^\alpha$, is it also true that $BC(\mathbf{p}_n, \mathbf{q}_n) \sim n^\alpha$ ?

Comment: Do you have $\sum p_i =\sum q_j =1$?

Comment: @Henry Yes, I implicitly assume that.

Comment: @Yikai It means that the asymptotic behavior of $d_E(\mathbf{p}_n, \mathbf{q}_n)$ is equivalent to $n^\alpha$.